# Gradient fill text effects

Tags: html, gradient

How to display gradient fill text without using image in html.

Comment: Also DocType specializes in HTML and web design problems, the link is also at the bottom of any page.

Comment: This is possibly a doctype question. If at most. What makes it programming related? The author is looking for a tool to display gradient fill text without using an image in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You should use SVG, Scalable Vector Graphics for that.

Comment: ...and RaphaelJS for the crappy IE. +1

Answer (score 0):

There are many online tools that create gradient text. Of course, each letter has 1 single  color.

For instance, you could use this tool: [Gradient Text Generator](http://tektek.org/color/). It generates BBCode and HTML code.

A Google search will find plenty of others, including several that can creates gradients between more than 2 colors.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
But I want to display more than one color for each letter in html(Linear Gradient).

Comment: Then it's not possible without using an image, or a Flash (or Silverlight) object.

Comment: I need the text as contenteditable. So by using an image its not possible. Any other way without using an image, or a Flash object.